# fls.doubleclick.net download slow only in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, google-tag-manager

When I connect the website, only IE 11 opened very slow because of fls.doubleclick.net,
not in safari, chrome.
I applied some solution in internet such as changing internet options about checking webpage
revocation, but it didn't`work.

Is there anyone who experienced about this?
And any solution about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [F12 developer Network tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v=vs.85)) to check the website resource loading time, we can see that it will spend too much time to load the JavaScript file and CSS style.

To improve the website performance, you could try to use the following methods:

1. [Improve the JavaScript script performance](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_performance.asp).
2. Use Specific CSS and Script files

   Using large CSS files that are used for the entire site in multiple pages will increase the loading time of the page thus leading to a performance hit. It can be split and stored in different files thus loading only what is required for each page. It will minimize the loading time of the pages.
3. User CDN reference.
4. Minify Resources (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript).

More detail information about Improve Web Application Performance, please refer the following links:

[Tips And Best Practices To Improve ASP.NET Web Application Performance](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tips-and-best-practices-to-improve-asp-net-web-application-performance/)

[Tips to Improve the Performance of an ASP.Net Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/skumaar_mca/tips-to-improve-the-performance-in-Asp-Net-application/)

[Minify Resources (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript)](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enSG881SG881&sxsrf=ACYBGNSy4D59eim6HKMBII6POlBT6Dur2w%3A1578927462896&ei=ZoUcXv6tNsTprQH-wqH4AQ&q=Minify%20Resources%20%28HTML%2C%20CSS%2C%20and%20JavaScript%29&oq=Minify%20Resources%20%28HTML%2C%20CSS%2C%20and%20JavaScript%29&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0j0i22i30.634248.634248..636180...0.1..0.119.119.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.WP7OjBe9NH4&ved=0ahUKEwj--LSU64DnAhXEdCsKHX5hCB8Q4dUDCAs)